# Where to put drawable resources for an OpenFL android extension?

Tags: java, android, haxe, openfl

I am making an android extension for my OpenFL app, which is supposed to show a notification, when I call a function from Haxe.

I need to put a drawable icon in my extension project, because a notification requires an icon.

However, the Java file extends an "Extension" class, which provides the object - Extension.assetManager (android.content.res.AssetManager)

How do I use this to access a drawable similar to R.drawable....?

And also where to put drawable resources for the OpenFL android extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [AssetManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open%28java.lang.String%29) can access files in the "assets" folder, so I suspect what you need to do is create this folder in the root of the extension project. To open the file, you'd use something like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(AssetManager.open("filename.png"));
```